# More efficient way of searching through a two-dimensional array than nested for-loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a function that takes in a two-dimensional array and a string. It then searches through the table and counts how many times the given string is found.

Here is the code:

```
function getNumberShifts(table, name) {

  var amount = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++){

      var text = table[i][j].toString();

      if(text.indexOf(name)>-1){
        amount += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return amount;
}
```

The 2D-array is not that big, about 30 x 60. Most of the cells are empty or contain 1 element (name). Sometimes it can contain two.

Is there a more efficient way than O(n^2)?
(This is a Google Sheets Script)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Example-table:

Time  | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Monday | ...
12:00| --name1 | ---name2 | ----name3 | ---name2 | name4 | ----name1 | name2 | ...
.
.
.

(Ignore the dashes, they are only for formatting purposes so you guys "see" the table)

This is basically it. Just a table with names. The top row and the left coloumn are not a part of the table that is sent to the function. Just the names. Some of the cells are completeley empty, (So it's easier to read it for me and my coworkers)

Comment: If you wrote your scripts in English, it'd be SO MUCH EASIER to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @MightyPork Easier for you, maybe, but probably not for OP. Really a little whitespace would help a lot more than putting the variable names (all of which are really obvious—`tabell` is "table," `tekst` is "text," and `navn` is "name"—and I don't even know what language it is) in English.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I edited it now. It's not really hard for me to translate it, but I thought that most of the variables were obvious to understand. Btw it's norwegian :)

Comment: input table sample please, maybe we can figure out a clever way.

Comment: @Gus Ortiz, sure. Is there a way to format tables on stackoverflow?

Comment: I was thinking in somethig like

var table = [["name1", "name2"],[] , ["name3"]];

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is no faster way of doing that. You need to check every single cell at least once.

Comment: That's what I thought. I was just hoping there was a way I didn't know of. Oh well :S

Comment: …unless you know more about the data and how it is structured, e.g. that it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it faster for *one* search.  As Safari points out, you have to look in every cell once, there are n^2 cells, so...

But if you are searching multiple times, it may make sense to preprocess the 2D array into a single hash-array.  So a n^2 set-up time but only a log(n) look-up time for each search.

```
var getNumberShiftsFinder = function(table) {
  var found = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
      var text = table[i][j].toString();
      found[text] = 1 + ( found[text] || 0 );
    }
  }
  return function(name) {
      return found[name] || 0;
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you explain how the code works? I really like programming and would like to learn more. And now I just have to figure out how to implement it into google-spreadsheet

Comment: For a given table, the code produces an associative array called `found`.  That array maps each string anywhere in the table to a count of how many times that string appears in the whole table.  It then returns an anonymous function that for any string, returns the contents of {{found}} for that string, or zero.  Does that help?  Note that this only matches the entire string, not substrings or anything like that that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that converting the array to a string and using string's indexOf,

incrementing the index after each match, would be less laborious than

iterating through the array.

```
function getNumberShifts(table, name){
    var i= 0, amount= 0, text= table.join(' ');
    while((i= text.indexOf(name,i)+1)){
        ++amount;
    }

    return amount;
}


var A1= [
    [0, "name2"], [1, ""], [2, "name2"], [3, ""], 
    [4, "name3"], [5, ""], [6, "name2"], [7, ""], [8, "name2"], [9, "name3"], 
    [10, "name2"], [11, ""], [12, "name2"], [13, ""], [14, "name3"], [15, ""], 
    [16, "name2"], [17, ""], [18, "name2"], [19, "name3"], [20, "name2"], 
    [21, ""], [22, "name2"], [23, ""], [24, "name3"], [25, ""], 
    [26, "name2"], [27, ""], [28, "name2"], [29, "name3"]
]
```

**getNumberShifts(A1, 'name3');**

/*  returned value: (Number)
6
*/